# Example from D book isn't working, odd error

Tags: 64-bit, d, 16-bit, xamarin-studio, dmd

All,

I'm using Xamarin Studio 4.08 and Mono-D to program D with the DMD2 compiler. When I try to compile the following (from [The D Programming Language - Alexandrescu](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361), 2010- Page 10):

```
import std.array;
bool binarySearch(T)(T[] input, T value)
{
    while (!input.empty)
    {
        auto i = input.length / 2;
        auto mid = input[i];
        if(mid > value) input = input[0 .. i];
        else if(mid < value) input = input[i + 1 .. $];
        else return true;
    }
    return false;
}

unittest
{
    assert(binarySearch([1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15], 6));
    assert(!binarySearch([1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 15], 5));
}
```

I get the following error upon compilation:

`: Error: std.array could not be resolved - library reference missing?`

However, the plot thickens when I comment out `assert(binarySearch([1,3,6,7,9,15], 6));`, because that produces a very peculiar error:

[image: lolwtfbbqsauce]

First, a library is missing, then, it's a 16-bit application. I know there's an errata for this book, but this isn't in it.

### UPDATE

Compiled with `rdmd test.d --main` and got the following errors, using the same code...

```
OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.13
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2010  All rights reserved.
http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html

OPTLINK : Warning 23: No Stack
C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)

Error 42: Symbol Undefined __fltused
C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
Error 42: Symbol Undefined __d_assert_msg

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
Error 42: Symbol Undefined __d_throwc

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std4conv21ConvOverflowException6__ctorMFAyaAyakZC
3std4conv21ConvOverflowException

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std4conv21ConvOverflowException7__ClassZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
Error 42: Symbol Undefined __d_newclass

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std4conv8__assertFiZv

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std4conv13ConvException7__ClassZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std4conv13ConvException6__ctorMFAyaAyakZC3std4con
v13ConvException

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D12TypeInfo_Aya6__initZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
Error 42: Symbol Undefined __d_arrayappendT

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std6format7__arrayZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __d_arraycopy

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std5array7__arrayZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _memcpy

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __d_newitemT

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D4core6memory2GC6extendFNaNbPvkkZk

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D4core6memory2GC6qallocFNaNbkkZS4core6memory8BlkInf
 o_

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __LDIV@

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D16TypeInfo_Pointer6__vtblZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D15TypeInfo_Struct6__vtblZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __ULDIV@

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std6format15FormatException6__ctorMFAyaAyakC6obje
 ct9ThrowableZC3std6format15FormatException

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std6format15FormatException7__ClassZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std3utf6encodeFNaNfKG4awZk

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std5array8__assertFiZv

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __d_arraysetcapacity

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std3utf8__assertFiZv

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std3utf7__arrayZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std3utf12isValidDcharFNaNbNfwZb

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std3utf12UTFException6__ctorMFAyakAyakC6object9Th
 rowableZC3std3utf12UTFException

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std3utf12UTFException7__ClassZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined __adDupT

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D14TypeInfo_Array6__vtblZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D10TypeInfo_a6__initZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D14TypeInfo_Const6__vtblZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D9Exception7__ClassZ

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std9exception7bailOutFNaNfAyakxAaZv

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std5ascii7isDigitFNaNbNfwZb

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D6object9Exception6__ctorMFNaNbNfAyaAyakC6object9Th
 rowableZC9Exception

C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\.rdmd\rdmd-test.d-AB3FF68B659C1090C52A7CFC868F
8061\objs\test.obj(test)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D3std5array12__ModuleInfoZ
OPTLINK : Warning 134: No Start Address
--- errorlevel 41
```

What'd I do wrong this time? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error in code.
Except, that it doesn't have a `main` function, so you can not run compiled program. You can ask the compiler to add `main` function for you. Just use `-main` switch.

`rdmd` is a [DMD Script Shell](http://dlang.org/rdmd.html).
You get errors because `rdmd` treats all arguments after file name as switches for your program. Try `rdmd --main test.d`.

Comment: Looking in the book (albeit a quick glance), none of the examples Andrei provides have both a `unittest` AND `main`.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer, I just added `void main() {}` and it compiles without any errors or warnings.

Comment: Note: I compile from console.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer One can generate stub `main` when running unittests like this: `rdmd --main -unittest code.d`
TDPL is written with using compiler via console in mind and can't be responsible for build setup for specific IDE.

Comment: So noted. I'll keep that in mind while using testunit examples.

Comment: Compiled with those options, produced errors edited into original post.